# Unable to create service

Tags: android, service, android-service

I'm new to android and creating a service in one of my reminder application. but I my service is triggering when i call the startService() in my onCreate() method of my activity I am unable to see the toasts which are used in different methods of my service class.As new to android unable to figure out the problem.
**MainActivity:**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_show_reminders);
        isReminders = false;
        dataSrc = new RemitDataSrc(this);
        dataSrc.open();

         rem = dataSrc.findALL();
        refreshDisplay();
    }
    private void refreshDisplay(){
        if(isMyServiceRunning(GeofencingService.class)){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofencingService.class);
            stopService(intent);
            Toast.makeText(this, "yes service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "No service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if(rem.size()==0){

            Toast.makeText(this, "No Reminders in Database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofencingService.class);
        startService(intent);
            ArrayAdapter<Reminders> remAdpt = new RemindersListAdapter(this, rem);
            setListAdapter(remAdpt);


    }
    private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**GeofencingService:**

```
public class GeofencingService extends Service{
    RemitDataSrc dataSrc;
    /**
     * Geofence Store
     */
    private GeofenceStore mGeofenceStore;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "GeoFencing Service created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        dataSrc = new RemitDataSrc(this);
        dataSrc.open();
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "GeoFencing Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        serviceTest sT= new serviceTest();
        dataSrc.open();

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "GeoFencing Service Stoped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        dataSrc.close();
    }

}
```

manifest.xml:

```
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SetReminderActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyD5GMap3cZBiMYWEiK0WX-2whx0xuqBwW4" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".AddReminderActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_reminder" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityShowReminders"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_activity_show_reminders" >
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name=".RemindersDetailActivity"
            android:label="Reminder Details" >
        </activity>
        <service 
            android:name=".LocationCheckerService"
            >

        </service>
         <service 
            android:name=".GeofencingService"
            android:exported="false"
            >

        </service>
    </application>
```

Comment: Well, first thing to do when something does not work on Android is to check [*logcat*](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) for error messages. Also: Is the service declared in your manifest? You don't check the return value from `startService()` so how are you sure, your service is actually found?

Comment: this is what I am using in manifest file `<service 
            android:name=".GeofencingService"
            android:exported="false"
            >
            
        </service>`

Comment: Please edit your question and add all relevant parts of the manifest. The dot indicates a relative name. Is the package name correct? Try to use the canonical class name of your service instead and see if that works. But most importantly: Check your calls for errors (you don't currently).

Comment: @dhke I think I m getting you as my service is another package com.afifa.projectreminder.service and the activity is in com.afifa.projectreminder

Comment: @dhke do I mention service like this  `<service 
            android:name="com.afifa.projectreminder.service.GeofencingService"
            android:exported="false"
            >`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have mentioned in one of one of your comments that the package name of service is different from the package containing activity, use the fully qualified class name in manifest with package name.

```
<service 
android:name="com.afifa.projectreminder.service.GeofencingService" android:exported="false" 
> 
</service>
```

Comment: Or if the app package is `foo.bar` and your component is `foo.bar.baz.Component`, you can just put `.baz.Component`.

Answer (score 0):

Please register your service to your manifest as a children of your application like:

```
<application ..>
..
    <service
            android:name=".GeofencingService"
            android:enabled="true">
    </service>
</application>
```

Comment: Its already done `<service 
            android:name=".GeofencingService"
            android:exported="false"
            >
            
        </service>`

Comment: add android:enabled="true"

Comment: I think by default its true http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html

Answer (score 0):

Mention the service in the manifest of your project under application Tag.
like so

```
<service android:name=".ServiceName" />
```